# Word arrangement in caches

Tags: cpu-cache

Why are the words in a cache line adjacent to one another?
Does this arrangement improve reading/writing performance or are there other reasons to justify this choice?

Answer (score 1):

Because it's common for programs to access data sequentially.

This arrangement of the cache will make sequential data access more efficient.  In particular, when the program accesses the first word, that word and subsequent words in the same cache line are all loaded into the cache, so when the program accesses the next word, it will already be cached and access will be very fast.

Any other arrangement would make sequential access slower.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I also have another question.

Comment: Why are the words in a cache line represented as a long sequence of consecutive bits, instead of the arrangement used in the main memory, where they are one on top of the other?

Comment: @user9880697, if you have another question, I encourage you to post it separately with the 'Ask Question' button.  In this case I don't understand what you are asking, so make sure to provide additional explanation and context.  I suggest you explain in the new question what you mean by "on top of the other" and explain your understanding of how cache works and how main memory works.